# Is there an industry-specific term for the animated logo that precedes a movie studio’s films?

Tags: terminology

Most studio films begin with an animated sequence that shows off the studio’s logo. For example, the [20th Century Fox “searchlights”](https://youtu.be/lsgSGHyXRiE) or the [Universal Studios Earth orbit](https://youtu.be/PvKiWRTSAzg). Is there an industry-specific term for this type of animated logo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [per Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Production_logo):

> A **production logo**, **vanity card**, **vanity plate**, or **vanity logo** is a logo used by movie studios and television production companies to brand what they produce and to determine the production company and the distributor of a television show or film. Production logos are usually seen at the beginning of a theatrical movie or video game (an **"opening logo"**), or at the end of a television program or TV movie (a **"closing logo"**).

Answer (score 4):

“Logos” or “film studio logos”.

See https://www.filmsite.org/titles-studiologos.html